# Handling Multiple Databases Data Syncing By Using Api Calls C# Mvc

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, api

I am Working with an application which maintains two different databases.
with almost similar data.
e.g If i create customer then that customer will be created/Saved in both databases.
One Db is Local and 2nd one on Remote Server i am accessing it through Api Calls.

As i create a new Customer and it get saved in local db but the api call (for remote db) fails
 or vice-versa,
 then how can i manage this scenario so that both databases remains synced and updated.
Most important thing is i cant add any new column or cant manipulate tables structure.

```
Example:
savedatatolive()
{
This save data to live server using api if this runs successfuly;
}

savedatatolocal()
{
This Save to local Db.If this creates issue or crashes while saving.
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. This is very likely going to be closed for either being too broad or for being primarily opinion based. I would suggest that you change direction entirely. Stop trying to write code manually to two databases. Instead look into using transactional replication. Will save you thousands of hours of pulling your hair out trying to keep two databases in synch.

Comment: agreed, don't do this. Use SQL replication to sync your databases, that's what it's for. This method is just asking for your data to become unreliable, all it takes is for one of the calls to fail unexpectedly for some reason and you're out of sync, and it's hard to roll back.